# find that two strings are cyclic

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

how to find that two strings are cyclic or not, in less than **O(n^2)**  and **without using a third array**.
**Input**
str1 = "abcde"  str="eabcd"
**output**
cyclic
**Input**
str1 = "cabdc"  str="ccabd"
**output**
cyclic
**Input**
str1 = "ddabnhdd"  str="dddabnhd"
**output**
cyclic

Please suggest me the best possible solution of it ???

Comment: Do you really mean less than O(n^2)? O(n^2) is not good enough?

Comment: O(n^2) is not good enough...thats why i posted the question.

Comment: and clearly you don't want to accept my without-a-third-array O(n) answer which is right. :(

Answer (score 4):

You need to do an optimized string search, there are ones that take `O(n) + O(m)`, you can find them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).
After that just double the first string and search the second in it, it will take `O(n)` time.
To avoid using a third array, just make every access to the first string modulo n.

Comment: Doubling the first string is essentially the same as using a third array I think.

Comment: OK, but all those methods involve building a complex data structure in order to speed the search. I think the intent of the question is to do this without additional memory allocation. I might be wrong.

Comment: @dani what we will search in first string (first char of other or a substring of other string) ?? what we get after optimize string search please elaborate taking one example ! 
and intension is to find solution with better time complexity and of course without additional memory allocation .....

Comment: Is there any optimal string search algorithm that doesn't need any additional array? As far as I know algorithms like KMP all need an additional array.

Answer (score 3):

The answer should be : [minimal-cyclic-shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459509/minimal-cyclic-shift-algorithm-explanation)

The algorithm costs O(n) time and no additional array at all, and it finds the
minimal cyclic shift of word.

using that, we can easily check :

```
int a=minLexCyc(str1),b=minLexCyc(str2),i,n=strlen(str1);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(str1[(a+i)%n]!=str2[(b+i)%n]){
                cout<< "not cyclic";
                return ;
        }
}
cout<< "cyclic";
```

PS: I don't think any solution that includes a **searching string** part will meet the requirement : **without using a third array** in **O(n)**. So maybe the minimal-cyclic-shift solution is the only one.

Comment: You should verify that both strings have the same length to avoid unpleasant surprises and possible wrong results, but good answer (I didn't know you could find the minimal cyclic shift in O(n) without an extra array, thanks for the link).